# Magento 2.2.2: Customer session not working with cache enable

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, session, customer-session

I tried this code but when cache is disable. it works, but when I enable cache it does not work.

```
$ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session =  $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($session->isLoggedIn()) 
{
}
```

Comment: in which file you are using this code?

Comment: i created one custom file for My account link in Magento_Theme Folder

Comment: Magento discourages us to use Object Manager directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use below code:**

```
$ObjectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
return $isLoggedIn;
```

Answer (score 9):

The best practice is to use `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` to check the customer logged in or not. And, avoiding using Object Manager directly.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Block\Account;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;

class Customer extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var HttpContext
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param HttpContext $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        HttpContext $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
     * Checking customer login status
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function customerLoggedIn()
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Khoa can you explain why this is best practice? I cannot find this in the Magento documentation.

Comment: @PatrickvanEfferen https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create()  the session, exactly you can force to get the current customer session with full page cache enabled. But i am not sure what principle it is using.

```
    $app = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');

    if ($app->getValue('customer_logged_in')) {

        $customerSession = $ObjectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create();

        $customerData = $customerSession->getData();

        $customerId = isset($customerData['customer_id'])?$customerData['customer_id']:'';
    }
```